# Sending form data with jQuery post method not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, post

Trying to update a delete flag in SQL Server through jQuery Ajax post method.  I am not sure if the issue is with my PHP or the jQuery code.  When I press the delete button nothing happens but the web dev tools do not indicate anything is wrong with the syntax.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class='dialog' id='editForm' title='Edit' >
        <form method='POST' id ='editFo' name = 'editFo' action='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        </form>
    </div>`
```

Here is the html for the button:

```
    <button id="deleteFormbtn" >Delete</button>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
    $("#deleteFormbtn").click(function(){
       $.post ( "deleteRow.php", $("#editForm: input").serializeArray(), function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });`
```

Here is the PHP code:

`

```
require_once ('sql/connectionstring/connectionstring.php');
$conn = SQLServerConnection();  


if(isset($_POST['vendor'])){

    $loc_sql = "SELECT TOP 1 loc_id FROM <table> WHERE loc_name = ?";
    $parms = array($_GET['loc']);
    $loc = sqlsrv_query($conn, $loc_sql, $parms) or die (print_r ( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    while ($q = sqlsrv_fetch_array($loc)){
        $loc_id = $q["loc_id"];
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $vendor_website = $_POST['website'];
    $vendor = $_POST['vendor'];


    $query = "UPDATE <table> SET <column> = '0' WHERE <column> = ?";

    $parms = $username;

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parms) or die (print_r ( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    sqlsrv_close($conn);

}
header('Location: <location>);
```

?>`

Comment: Are you seeing a POST request in the dev tools/network tab or any errors in the console?

Comment: The console shows no errors out output and nothing happens in the network tab when i click the button

Comment: I suspect this is your first issue. Change your button to `<button type="button" id="deleteFormbtn">Delete</button>`. As is the page is reloading and request is never sent.

Comment: I have made that change, but still nothing happening in the network tab.

Comment: `$("#editForm: input")` is the wrong selector... you'd want to serialize the form, so use this selector: `$('#editFo')`

Comment: Made this edit, still no change.  Thank you though that is part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to pass the 'vendor' with the AJAX post request so PHP can recognize it when trying to access `$_POST['vendor']`
- You also need to handle when "`if(isset($_POST...) { .... }`" isn't fulfilled so it gets back with an error.
- Focus more on the PHP part to send you a reply in JSON.
  Something similar to:

  $data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Isn't 'vendor' being passed through the editForm input?  That is one of my array elements.

Comment: I can't see it in the example you posted. Could you please post more on the html part.

Comment: In all cases, the PHP part needs to be improved to give you proper result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `type="button"` to your button, otherwise the page reloads and request will not be sent because it defaults to "submit".

```
<button type="button" id="deleteFormbtn" >Delete</button>
```

Additionally, you are referencing the `div` not the `form` in your AJAX request. You don't need the `method` or `action` attributes, AJAX handles that for you. Send the entire form instead of just the `input`.

```
<div class='dialog' id='editForm' title='Edit' >
  <form id ='editFo' name = 'editFo' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  </form>
</div>

$("#deleteFormbtn").click(function(){
  $.post ("deleteRow.php", $("#editFo").serialize(), function(data){
    alert(data);
  });
});
```